# Knockout mapping not working with array of checkboxes

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to implement select all/none functionality on a list of checkboxes.

Clicking select all should select the three checkboxes. In the broken example, clicking select all does not update the checkboxes. It does update the array however.

This fiddle works: [Working Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rboarman/gGQ5M/)

This fiddle does not: [Broken Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rboarman/ZeCWP/5/)

The only difference between the two is that ko.mapping is called which does not seem to be setting up the observable array correctly.

```
var initialData = {"Products":[{"Id":"1","Title":"Item 1"},{"Id":"2","Title":"Item 2"},{"Id":"3","Title":"Item 3"}]};  

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `ko.mapping`, *every* property of the input becomes an `observable`.

That means in your first sample you can do:

```
viewModel.selectAll = function() {
    viewModel.checkedProducts.removeAll();
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.Products(), function(product) {
        viewModel.checkedProducts.push(product.Id);  // Id is a plain value
    });
};
```

while in your mapping sample you must do:

```
viewModel.selectAll = function() {
    viewModel.checkedProducts.removeAll();
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.Products(), function(product) {
        viewModel.checkedProducts.push(product.Id());  // Id is an observable!
    });
};
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZeCWP/6/

---

Really clean would be this:

```
viewModel.selectAll = function() {
    viewModel.checkedProducts.removeAll();
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.Products(), function(product) {
        viewModel.checkedProducts.push( ko.utils.unwrapObservable(product.Id) );
    });
};
```

This would work in both cases. But in a controlled environment it's not strictly necessary to use `unwrapObservable()` since you know that the value will always be the an observable or not.

Comment: You're the man. You have no idea how much time I've spent on this. Thank you.

Comment: @rboarman Small hint for future debugging. Add a `<div data-bind="text: $parent.property">` (or whatever value you're interested in) somewhere. Knockout does one level of unwrapping by itself for data-bound values (in fact, it uses `unwrapObservable()` interally). So if you see a plain value, you're good. If you see `function c(){if(0<arguments.length) etc etc ...` you're facing an observable that contains an observable. That means you forgot to unwrap an observable along the way.